# Is it possible to create Thematic Maps using two columns in Mapinfo?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I have created Thematic map with one column in Mapinfo. Is it possible to create Thematic Map using two columns in Mapinfo?

For Example:

> I have a column with name of place and a column with date. Is it
>   possible to combine name of place and date to generate thematic map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could choose the "Expression..." at the end of the list of columns when choosing the table/layer and field to use for your thematic map. This would allow you to combine these two columns using the Expression dialog with a statement like this:

```
name_of_place + " " + some_date_column
```

It is alse possible to create Bivariate Thematic Mapping - have a look in the help system in MapInfo Pro to read more about this